# Error: Unsupported type for GM_setValue. Supported types are: string, bool, and 32 bit integers

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

So, I have GreaseMonkey Script that does some operations with integers and then sets value via `GM_setValue`.

**Code**:

```
  var A = parseInt(StringA);
  var B = parseInt(StringB);
  var C = parseInt(StringC);
  var answer = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.max((A/B),1)*C));
  GM_setValue("answer",answer);
```

Now this works perfectly fine in Chrome, but somehow fails in Firefox, giving

`Error: Unsupported type for GM_setValue. Supported types are: string, bool, and 32 bit integers.`

The value A, B and C are properly being exported, even the value of answer is calculated as expected. Checked it with `alert` dialogue-boxes.
Only problem is, it is not setting value via `GM_setValue`. Earlier I wasn't doing `parseInt` on `var answer` as type of `Math.floor` already should return the integer, but just doing it anyway. (In both cases answer is correct, but giving errors.)

I fail to understand what's going wrong here. Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Not sure how it matters, but here's the sample output via `alert("A: "+A+"\nB: "+B+"\nC: "+C+"\n\nAnswer: "+answer);`

```
A: 41751
B: 20513
C: 190164861567

Answer: 387050803650
```

Comment: And what is the value of `answer` ?

Comment: Added sample values and output. Not sure why that matters, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add [`radix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) value to your parseInt function:

```
parseInt(Math.floor(Math.max((A/B),1)*C), 10);
```

**Update:**

Your value is too big for GM scripts to store. The max 32-bit supported number in mozilla `2147483647` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers).

To store your value try to convert it to string for example:

```
GM_setValue("answer", "" + answer + "");
```

or using `toString()` method:

```
GM_setValue("answer", answer.toString());
```

Comment: That worked. I tried `alert(typeof(answer))` and that gave out as `number` instead of `integer`, so I used `answer.toString()`. But basically you're right. Thanks. Aha, Just noticed you suggested `toString` too. Thanks